countreg package not available in r version 4.4.0
I recently updated r to 4.4.0 version.  I attempted to install countreg package for analysis of count data but it is not available for this latest version of r.  Does anyone know of an alternative or another way of installing this package?
I have gone to the cran website but there isn't really any info on an alternative

It seems like countreg never was on CRAN in the first place, see for example this email from the r-devel list. As
countreg is here on r-forge and mirrored at github so you could try
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/r-forge/countreg", subdir="pkg")


That works, thanks so much!

My pleasure!  Please feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer.
